# Building a swc in command line or ant

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ant, flash-builder, swc

First off - I'm not super familiar with Flash Builder or ActionScript.  I have an ActionScript project in Flash Builder.  I know I can generate a `swc` file by doing Project > Build, and it will build a `swc` file from my ActionScript source code.

Is there a way to generate the `swc` in command line or ant?  I'd like to be able to put this build process inside a build script so I don't need to go through Flash Builder to build the `swc` file everytime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see `compc`.

```
compc -source-path . -include-classes MyComponent -output MyComponent.swc
```

`MyComponent.as` (source file for `MyComponent`) is in the current directory, which is why `-source-path` is set to `.`.

If you have many classes for your library, you can use a manifest file with a namespace.

See:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_22.html

There's also the `compc` ant task.